# How to use wkhtmltopdf-binary in test envoirnment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf

I want to write a test case to verify behavior of pdf generation. `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary', '~> 0.9.9.3'` is already added in my development group, now i add it in test group as well. After writing the test case when i run it then it gives following error:

> PDFKit::NoExecutableError: No wkhtmltopdf executable found at
>   /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf

This is what i have in my pdfkit.rb file.

```
 PDFKit.configure do |config|
      config.wkhtmltopdf = '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
    end
```

**Pdf is running fine in development envoirnment, but its test case is giving error**, how can i fix this issue ? I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

ok i got it, The problem was path for executable has been changed from `'/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'` to some other directory. So i just remove the binary from `'/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'` with command

```
 sudo rm -r /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

After that i found the new binary path by running `which wkhtmltopdf` and then create a symbolic link by running command

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /home/confiz/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Which solved my problem